# Lasso cross-validation plot looks weird

Tags: feature-selection, lasso

My dataset is about the Airbnb room rental price, after encoding dummy variables, data cleaning etc., left 30 features, 7770 rows. Price is the response. The link to download the dataset is here, http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data.html. After I run lasso <- cv.glmnet(x.train, y.train, alpha = 1), then I plot(lasso), however the plot looks weird. When lambda increases, the MSE should increase, but my plot shows when lambda increases, MSE becomes zero. [image]

The feature left in the dataset after my cleaning is here, 
[2] "host_response_rate"                 "host_total_listings_count"
[3] "accommodates"                       "bathrooms"
[5] "bedrooms"                           "beds"
[7] "security_deposit"                   "cleaning_fee"
[9] "guests_included"                    "extra_people"
[11] "minimum_nights"                     "maximum_nights"
[13] "review_scores_rating"               "calculated_host_listings_count"
[15] "reviews_per_month"                  "host_period"
[17] "price"                              "host_is_superhost_t"
[19] "host_has_profile_pic_t"             "host_identity_verified_t"
[21] "is_location_exact_t"                "instant_bookable_t"
[23] "require_guest_profile_picture_t"    "require_guest_phone_verification_t"
[25] "room_type_Private.room"             "room_type_Shared.room"
[27] "bed_type_Couch"                     "bed_type_Futon"
[29] "bed_type_Pull.out.Sofa"             "bed_type_Real.Bed"
[31] "cancellation_policy_moderate"       "cancellation_policy_strict"

The result from cv.glmnet is 
Lambda Measure       SE Nonzero 
min 0.05758  0.3641 0.002261       6 
1se 0.05758  0.3641 0.002261       6

The coefficient for those 6 variables are all very small cleaning_fee                   0.0003200325, accommodates 0.0952141819, review_scores_rating           0.0045013762, room_type_Private.room -0.2448280933, room_type_Shared.room            -0.8304957776, bedrooms 0.0810685740. Maybe that is the reason? So even lambda is larger, the MSE does not change much?

Please help...

Comment: Can you tell us more about your dataset?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. My dataset is the Airbnb room rental price, after encoding dummy variables, data cleaning etc., left 85 features. Price is the response, predictors are cleaning fees, deposit, beds, is_super_host, etc...

Comment: Are the MSEs actually zero for larger lambda, or is it just the scale of the plot making it look that way?  Are MSEs on the order of 10^11 reasonable for this dataset?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How is this MSEs in the plot calculated? I thought MSEs does not include lambda, just sigma square y - y_hat. Do I miss something here?

Comment: I meant that given the scale of the y-axis in your plot, perhaps the MSEs on the right side of the plot are actually ~10^5, not actually zero.  And I'm curious whether 10^11 is a sign of something amiss: what's the scale of the prices?

Comment: Which of the datasets at that link (which city) are you working with?  Could you provide your data cleaning procedure?

Comment: I use San Francisco. All feature are transformed to numeric, including using dummy to transform categorical variables.  I can show you the result from cv.glmnet is as below.   Measure: Mean Absolute Error 

     Lambda Measure       SE Nonzero
min 0.05758  0.3641 0.002261       6
1se 0.05758  0.3641 0.002261       6

Comment: I edited in my original post, the result of the cv.glmnet and the features after my data cleaning, please refer to the post.